# How protect API routes?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to protect data in JSON routes that will talk to my Angular controllers in the client-side.

I have some routes that return data in JSON format, I will give an example:

`/api/events` - returns all events 
`/api/events/:slug` - returns only one event

`/api/bookings` - returns all bookings 
`/api/bookings/:slug` - returns only one booking

I'm searching a lot, and I find it two answers, protect by domain, and by token, so. Which one is the right one for that?

And how the token protects works? If I send a token that anyone can find in my client code, it's kind of useless, right?

Comment: You can always generate a unique API key for every user who is going to use your API. Then, this key should be part of every request so that you can check if it is valid.

Comment: But how protect this key in the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A suggestion and basic explanation ;

Use Token based authentication for your rest client. And also you can specify cors filter for your rest backend.

Specify Access-Control-Allow-Origin in your cors filter to allow only your domain so in client side user knows token but another domain or locally he/she can't send any request restricted areas.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.yourdomain.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type
```

Send retrieved token in your requests with authorization header `Authorization: Bearer userToken`.

Basic token auth flow according to your second question ;

```
Client tries to login -> Server check username pass etc. and sends token to client -> Client saves token in localStorage or cookie -> Sending token in request with Authorization header -> Server tokenfilter checks is token valid -> accessed restricted area
```

According to the your first question, use both tokenfilter and corsfilter together.

Comment: Thanks! That is what i as searching for.. But tell me something if you know. I was searching here and i find it a guy saying that Express.js already prevents CORS.

Comment: Here is a good example about cors enabling in Express.js http://jonathanmh.com/how-to-enable-cors-in-express-js-node-js/

Answer (score 1):

Tokens are called JWT that stands for JSON Web Tokens. They are one of the major and very easy ways for authenticating a user.

JWT are a long string consisting of three parts devided by dots. Each one is base64 encoded:

- The first one is called header and contains some basic information about the token.
- The second one is the payload. Here is stored information you want to transfer between the client and the api. Usually it is a user id or so. That way the api can authenticate the user.
- The third part is the signature. This is the part that is making the token secure. The signature consists of the header and the payload encoded with a secret that only the api knows.

So the JWT lifecycle is very easy:

1. You sign up / sign in the user and send to the client a JWT that is stored in the local or cookie storage of the users browser.
2. With AngularJS you can make an interceptor that will send the token to the api with each request using an authorization header.
3. In the api on each route that you want to protect you will use a middleware that will decode the JWT and check if the user id match an user in your database. That way you will protect your routes from unauthorized requests.

You can find of course nice third party libraries for using JWT, interceptors in AngularJS and middleware in Node.js.

[Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) is very nice front end library for AngularJS providing you with easy local authentication as well as very easy authentication using a lot of social networks like facebook, twitter, github and so on. It includes that interceptor so that you wont need to write it yourself and also it has a lot of examples for your server side code.

For more information about the JWT you should definitely check out my article: [Json Web Tokens over Cookies for authentication](http://team.158ltd.com/2015/07/10/4023/)

And also I will give you a link to very good course on Pluralsight that gave me a lot of knowledge about AngularJS, NodeJS and JWT authentication: [Creating Apps With Angular, Node, and Token Authentication](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/creating-apps-angular-node-token-authentication)

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in a repo I just created.  Its a basic node API with token authentication using Json Web Tokens.  The idea as some of the others have stated is when creating a user or logging in, a token is created and stored client side.  This is sent in an Authorization header with every request and the system determines whether the user of that token has authorization to access that endpoint.

[Here's the repo](https://github.com/drhurdle/node-rethinkdb-auth-starter)

Tokens are generated in the

> /server/services/tokenAuth.js

To protect endpoints, all you have to do is add **isAuthorized** to your protected routes. This calls

> /server/policies/isAuthorized.js

to do the actual check

This repo is still a work in progress but should be able to help you get started with JWT's.